# Best way to combine ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView and View

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new with react-native and I would like to ask you what is best way to combine (in the same screen) this elements.

The use case is that I have to show a page with 10 inputs so user have to scroll screen and if he open last input this can't be covered from keyboards

Based on your experience, what is best order to combine this elements?

**First example**

```
<ScrollView>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView>
    <View>
      // My content here
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</ScrollView>
```

**or second example..**

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
  <ScrollView>
    <View>
      // My content here
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: You probably want your `ScrollView` inside your `KeyboardAvoidingView`. Also be sure to note message about `flex:1` in [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview). And you'll probably want to take a look at `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` on the same doc page. `handled` has worked best for me in the past, otherwise your keyboard will be popping in and out every time you switch between inputs.

Comment: One other thing, you'll need to make sure you have the `flex:1` in the `contentContainerStyle` of `KeyboardAvoidingView`, as well as the regular `style` for the same element. Otherwise it will still end up collapsing.